# Re-encode corrupt videos (that still play) and drop bad frames FFMPEG or other app?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have about 300GB of assets that have been deemed "corrupt" by FFprobe but most all of them still have playable portions of the video.

What I've been trying to determine how to do is either one at a time or in batch, use FFMPEG or another app/tool to re-encode the assets dropping all the bad frames leaving me with an albeit, still not 100% complete, but at least usable assets.

Can anyone shed any light on this? Offer any ideas or suggestions? I can run on either Windows, MacOS or Linux OS and am competent with basic scripting and terminal command usage.

Thank you!

Jason

Answer (score 1):

I would try TMPG Smart Renderer, https://tmpgenc.pegasys-inc.com/en/product/tmsr6.html. It should just "pass-through" any non-corrupted video, and will re-encode the portions of the file the need to be. Or you can manually cut those pieces out. It will depend how corrupt the input is as to what you'll need to do. It is a commercial product, but for a one-off project you can likely do everything you need in trial mode.